# Erro em Somatória de frações condicionais

Tags: c, programação-estruturada

nao consigo fazer esse exercicio usando for, poderiam me ajudar.
Nao consigo achar onde estou errando, coloquei dois && no for para realizar as duas operacoes porem nao esta compilando, obrigado.

Elabore um programa em C que calcule e imprima o somatório expresso pela seguinte série:

S = 500/2 + 480/3 + 460/4 + ....

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
int x, y;
float z;
x = 2;
y = 500;
z = 0;
for (;x = 20 %% y = 26; x = x - 20 && y = y + 1)
    z = z + x/y;

printf("%f", z);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Você está fazendo uma divisão de inteiros (x / y). Utilize um cast para float: z += (float)  x / y;. Além disso é && e não %%. Na Parte final do for utilize apenas ,: x -=  20 , y++.

Comment: Mais simples seria: for (x = 500, y = 2; x >= 20 &&  y <= 26; x -= 20 , y++)

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas pessoal, pior que continua dando erro..

Comment: Veja: http://ideone.com/x1CQB1

Comment: Mas ai ja sabe o valor exato de parcelas, eu nao sei o numero de parcelas

Comment: Então qual é a condição para você parar de somar?